# Using after_create to Create another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a "robot" that automatically makes a comment based on another comment's content. I have an after_create callback that is used to call a method that checks if a string is included in the message of the comment. What I want to happen is, if the string isn't found, create a comment reply saying something.

I haven't worked much with callbacks and have gotten some stack level too deeps and some all around different errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me a little insight?

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :children, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => 'Comment'
  after_create do |comment|
    if comment.check_comment_contents! == :github_and_heroku
      c = Comment.new(:title=>"TSTSTTTsafdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfTSTSTTTsafdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf",
        :message => "TSTSTTTsafdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfTSTSTTTsafdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf",
        :parent_id => nil,
        :forum_id => 1,
        :lesson => 1
        )
    end
end
```

I was trying to do something like this just for testing, but I feel it is already extremely messy and not well thought out.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Are you intending to save that new Comment or just initialize it and throw it out?

Comment: I'm intending to save it.

Comment: The point is you're not saving it, and there's no way to save it once you exit that block, it's lost forever, just garbage waiting to be collected.

Comment: This is leading to infinite loop ,so you are getting stack level too deep error.if you want to simply create another comment then skip validation while saving.

Comment: So, you're saying if i just do a c.save after creating the comment it should work?

I'm not at home right now... However the code I tried before this was Comment.create with all of the params inside of it and it gave me an error also.